# Does the order of event registration in NIO matter?

Tags: java, selector, nio

The canonical way of using a `Selector` in java NIO is :

1. regist the a `ServerSocketChannel` with the `SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT` event type .
2. invoke `select` method (which block the thread)in a loop method
3. then when a `OP_ACCEPT` event happened , and the relative `AcceptEventHandler` is invoked to accept a `SocketChannel`
4. then regist the accepted `SocketChannel` with the `SelectionKey.OP_READ` event type.
5. when a read event happend , the `ReadEventHandler` handle the inputs and then regist the `SocketChannel` with a `SelectionKey.OP_WRITE` event type.

My question is, why don't register three event type at once at the beginning? Does the sequence make any sense?

Comment: It depends on the protocol, but generally (picture an HTTP server), you don't register them all at once because you'll be notified that you can write to the socket before you're read anything, and with nothing to write, you'll keep getting notified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The canonical way of using a `Selector` in java NIO is:

No it isn't. See below.

> why don't register three event type at once at the beginning?

Because you can't. You don't have the accepted channel until you call `accept()`, and you don't do that until you have registered OP_ACCEPT and had it fire, and you can't register the accepted channel for anything until you have it.

> does the sequence make any sense?

Nothing *else* would make sense.

NB you don't register OP_WRITE until you've encountered a short or zero-length write. The reason is that it is almost always ready, so the strategy is simply to write when you have something to write, and only use OP_WRITE to tell you when it becomes possible to write again after a short write (which means the socket send buffer was full).

Comment: Tks man , u explained quite clear ,  OP_READ and OP_WRITE is regist on Selector with a SocketChannel , which i can't have it before i do accept operation ...

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to try to add something to the conversation.

A `ServerSocketChannel` can only `accept()` new connections.  `OP_READ` / `OP_WRITE` won't do you anything there.  I'm pretty sure you can add them but they will just be ignored because the `ServerSocketChannel's` only responsibility is to `accept()` remote `SocketChannel`.

Once you `accept()` and get a new `SocketChannel`; you want to listen to `OP_READ` first.  If you listen to `OP_WRITE` then most likely you will get the `OP_WRITE` returned to you every single time you call `select()` and that will consume lots of resources.

You only want to listen to `OP_WRITE` when you tried to write some data to the `SocketChannel` and not all the data was written.